# PYSVN commit as another user

Tags: python-2.7, pysvn

I need to find a way to their commit as another user OR edit the commit user after the commit, but I have been unable to find anything on the internet other than this code snippet:

> svn ps --revprop -r $revision svn:author $patch_submitter $repository_url

The idea is that we have a system that our users use to edit some fields, they are logged into that system and we want to avoid having to prompt for a password when they click save.

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_revpropset

rev = \
revpropset( prop_name,
            prop_value,
            url,
            revision=pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.head ),
            force=False )

set the revision property prop_name to prop_value in path. The revision updated is returned.

Barry (pysvn maintainer)